# Is there a way to avoid multi clicking on an event in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

When I click on the button it just speeds up the timer. The more I click the faster it gets

```
playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (timerStatus == "Stopped") {

    timerInterval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
    document.getElementById('startstopBtn').innerHTML = ` <i class="fa-solid fa-play" id="play"></i>`
    timerStatus = "Stopped"

  }
```

I tried to make it happen only once.

Comment: Every time you click on the button you start another interval timer, but you never stop the previous one. So they're all running simultaneously.

Comment: Put `clearInterval(timerInterval)` to stop the old one.

Comment: I did, but still it doesn't work.
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    window.clearInterval(timerInterval)
    second = 0;
    minute = 0;
    hour = 0;
    document.getElementById('timer').innerText = "00:00:00"
})

Comment: Why do you do `timerStatus = "Stopped"` when you start the timer? I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The timer is speeding up because you are calling new intervals again and again when you are clicking the button and each of them is calling with its own interval. It is like starting timers on multiple clocks one after another.

Like @Barmar mentioned, the solution is to clear the interval on each new click if it already exists. I see that you are creating a new reset button to do this, which is not necessary.

For it to work as expected, you need to do something like this:

```js
const playBtn = document.querySelector('button');

function stopWatch() {
    console.log('clicked');
}

const handleClick = (() => {
    let timerInterval;
  return () => {
    if(timerInterval) return;
    timerInterval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
  }
})();

playBtn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <button>
    play
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to restart the timer on each click with the same interval, without speeding up, then use this:

```js
const playBtn = document.querySelector('button');

function stopWatch() {
    console.log('clicked');
}

function handleClick() {
    let timerInterval;
  return () => {
    timerInterval && clearInterval(timerInterval);
    timerInterval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
  }
}

playBtn.addEventListener('click', handleClick());
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <button>
    play
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I realised it is not even necessary to clear the timer interval because you mentioned that you only want to run it once i.e only on the first click of the button. Am I right?

Instead, if you want the new timer to start at the point you click and show the intervals then, like resetting the timer and starting new each time, you would need to clear the interval. Let me know which it is so I can help you further.